# RedirectToAction redirecting to wrong User ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Edit**: I am still encountering this issue but I have solved it displaying the applications on 2 users profile instead of the user that created it. I am still running into the issue of redirecting to the wrong ID however and I can't find any information online about it. All the breakpoints up to the redirect point to the correct ID so I am really perplexed. As stated below, I had altered my viewbag and variables to be consistent and it did not fix the issue.

---

I have an application that allows users to add applications to their profile. Their profile will list all of the applications made by that user. The application has been configured in the RouteConfig file to initialise the application in the profile of UserId 1.

What is happening is that if I create an application for UserId 1, it works fine, adds the application to the list of applications for UserId 1 and displays it. If I create a new user (UserId 2) and then proceed to add a new application for that user, the redirect action that happens when the application is submitted to the database takes me back to UserId 1's page with the application being added to UserId 1's list and also to the UserId that created it (In this instance, UserId 2). I'm not sure why this is happening as I am explicitly telling it to get the UserId from the ViewBag that is storing the correct UserId.

If I look into the database, there is only 1 record for the application. I can delete the application in UserId 1's list and it will still exist in UserId 2's list and also the database. If I remove it through the UserId 2's page, it will remove the record from all lists and database. This also applies to updating the details of the application.

When I've set a breakpoint at the very end where the controller will pick up the UserId and then redirect me to that UserId's page. It states the correct UserId's page it needs to redirect to (In the scenario above, it states the UserId is 2). However, as already stated, it is redirecting me to the UserId 1.

If I remove the route in the RouteConfig file that initialises the application in UserId 1 and just load up the default index page, create a user then create an application, I am given an error stating System.NullReferenceException because I'm trying to display the name of the user using - `<h2>User Profile for @Model.Name</h2>` so it's not picking up the details of the UserId. I'm not sure why this is happening either as I thought the RouteConfig file was purely to tell the application where to inialise.

Code below, some points to make:

- This is what the URL looks like when I am about to submit the application =       `https://localhost:44313/Service/AddApplication?Course=Level1&DriverId=1&UserId=2`
- RoutesConfig is sending to "GetUser", "User", 1 at application start
- The viewbags are working as I can see that it picks up the correct UserId at the very end of the adding process.

**Controller Action to Add Application;**

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNewApplication(ApplicationAdd applicationAdd, string UserId, int DriverId)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add insert logic here
            applicationService.AddApplication(applicationAdd, UserId, DriverId);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { UserId =  ViewBag.UserId });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**GetUser action in User Controller:**

```
        public ActionResult GetUser(string id)
    {
        return View(userService.GetUser(id));
    }
```

**GetUser action in userService:**

```
        public User GetUser(string id)
    {
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            return userDAO.GetUser(id, context);
        }
    }
```

**GetUser in userDAO:**

```
        public User GetUser(string id, MyContext context)
    {
        context.Users.Include(g => g.Applications).ToList();
        return context.Users.Find(id);
    }
```

**RouteConfig file path:**

```
defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "GetUser", id = 1 }
```

**Controller Action that is giving the view to display the list of applications for a user:**

```
        public ActionResult GetApplications(string id)
    {
        User user = userService.GetUser(id);
        IList<Application> applications = user.Applications.ToList();
        return View(applications);
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code and check what values are being posted to `AddNewApplication` and `GetUser` action method?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya yes I did state what the values were in the post. When I look at the breakpoint for the line - applicationService.AddApplication(applicationAdd, UserId, DriverId);    It shows me the correct UserId (2)  and DriverId (1) and the line after - return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { UserId =  ViewBag.UserId }); shows UserId being set to 2 but still redirects me to UserId 1 or to the index page.

Comment: Try changing `new { UserId = ViewBag.UserId }` to `new { id = ViewBag.UserId }`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I've just tried to follow the advice and rename all UserId to id in actions and hyperlinks and still is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { id =  ViewBag.UserId });
```

the parameter name `UserId` needs to be the same as the one in the funcation `id`.

Comment: I've tried this, changed all variables to follow id instead of UserId and it hasn't worked. Still just redirects to UserId 1

Comment: Just for safety, I also tried renaming all to UserId and that hasn't worked either. I have a feeling it is something to do with the fact I am initialising in UserId 1 from the RouteConfig but can't pinpoint the exact issue.